Conditional replacement in Google sheets array matching row and header values
Looking for a formula that can replace any value in an array that matches the row 1 value and corresponding column value in a table
input would include providing the row the corresponding values(ie A1:C1,A2:C3)
and providing the matching table locations to match  (ie ReplaceTable!A:A, B:B) and the corresponding replacement value (ie ReplaceTable! C:C) as in the tables below
ValueTable!



1
2
3




John
Green
1


Mary
Red
2



ReplaceTable!



ID
Value
RegexReplace




1
"^(\w+)"
"$1"


2
Green
is happy


2
Red
is sad


2
Orange
is scared


2
Red
is mad


3
1
2


3
2
1



ResultsTable



{Formula}
2
3




John
is happy
1


Mary
is sad
2



=makearray(rows(A2:C3),columns(A1:C1),lambda(r,c,let(Σ,ifna(filter(F:G,E:E=index(A1:C1,,c))),if(Σ="",,reduce(index(A2:C,r,c),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(f,q,regexreplace(f&"",index(index(Σ,,1),q)&"",index(index(Σ,,2),q))))))

produces the following result
|1|2|3|
|---------|---------|---------|
|John|two|1|
|Mary|is sad|1|
as can be seen in test sheet
I believe this is a variation of either a query() or indexmatch() where some of the values are TRANSPOSED, perhaps using a queryand then looking this value up.
In several steps I could accomplish something similar by doing the following as can be seen in the table below.



Values Table






1
2
3


John
Green
one


Mary
Red
two







ReplaceTable




QID
Choice
RegexReplace


1
"^(\w+)"
"$1"


2
Green
is happy


2
Red
is sad


2
Orange
is scared


2
Red
is mad


3
one
misses his mom.


3
two
misses his dad.







Transposed ReplaceTable




1
John
Mary


2
Green
Red


3
one
two







Results Using Formulas in Row1




1
John
Mary


2
is happy
is sad


3
misses his mom.
misses his dad.







Row 1 formulas




=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup({$A$18:$A$20&A18:A20},{$A$8:$A$15&$B$8:$B$15,$C$8:$C$15},2,false),A18:A20))
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup({$A$18:$A$20&B18:B20},{$A$8:$A$15&$B$8:$B$15,$C$8:$C$15},2,false),B18:B20))
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup({$A$18:$A$20&C18:C20},{$A$8:$A$15&$B$8:$B$15,$C$8:$C$15},2,false),C18:C20))







Results using individual formulas transposed back




1
2
3


John
is happy
misses his mom.


Mary
is sad
misses his dad.





You may try:
=makearray(rows(A2:C3),columns(A1:C1),lambda(r,c,let(Σ,ifna(filter(F:G,E:E=index(A1:C1,,c))),if(Σ="",,
 reduce(index(A2:C,r,c),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(f,q,regexreplace(f&"",index(index(Σ,,1),q)&"",index(index(Σ,,2),q))))))))



Adjust the ranges accordingly as per the data structure in your sheet


Adapted the question. Currently, if any of the RegexReplace values in G:G = F:F for a given ID it will introduce an error.

Adapted the question. Currently, if any of the RegexReplace values in G:G = F:F for a given ID in E:E it will introduce an error. For example, if I set 3, 1, 2 & 3, 2, 1 as in the adapted example above, it replaces both 1 and 2 with 1. This reproduces it seems any time where one of the RegexReplace parameters for a given ID are the same as a value in F:F. How can this formula be adapted to avoid this?

Share a test sheet

ok will set this up and share

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a9CukA5pR65IPBf5D2ia9zSAc8iIHh9lLpB69nOIxG4/edit?usp=sharing

Showcase the ideal expected output by entering it manually

Adapted showcase, additional test cases. The current behavior allows Regexreplace table to change values that have already been changed (nesting). The desired behavior would be to only change values in the values table similar to switch =arrayformula(iferror(switch(C2:C5, "two", "one", "one", "two", "three", "four"),C2:C5)) rather than as a nested substitute =arrayformula(iferror(substitute(substitute(substitute(C2:C5, "three", "four"), "two", "one"), "one", "two"), C2:C5)). See test sheet.

test out the formula added in cell L28
